Cannot save cookies on localhost
I am trying to implement persistent login for my React + Express application. My API has a /login endpoint which seems to work when tested with REST client VS code extension.
Ploblem is when I call the /login endpoint in React (using the fetch API) I receive a response with the following headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: connect.sid=s%3AjXUTczU7_hgAHbI3v96qbAGLWTQsFAlV.X5i9E%2F8EkU3eCIB95CpS0%2BpzbAcGq9CtoBe7LfDODjo; Path=/; HttpOnly

Which seems to correctly set the cookie in the browser but when I check with ChromeDevTools under F12 > application > cookies > localhost I can't find it.
Now I have seen related questions and the answers were suggesting to use 'include' in the fetch() or other settings like this but this solves the problem when the cookie is saved and not sent by the client on successive requests (am I correct?).
If I receive a cookie I should be able to see it in the ChromeDevTools under cookies I suppose, so this seems a different problem. (I will be happy to edit with further info but maybe I am missing something)

include mode option in fetch() means that cookies can be sent across origins. Also keep in mind that 127.0.0.1 and localhost are different origins. The OS treats them both the same way in some cases but they are actually different origins.

"Which seems to correctly set the cookie in the browser". How do you mean? Where exactly is it set correctly?

I am doing everything localhost I am not using 127.0.0.1

Testing with REST client I cannot see the saved coookie (even though I see the set-cookie header same as in the network tab of devtools) but when testing other routes which require auth it works and it stops working when I logout (so desired behaviour)

Do read the question before closing as a duplicate. These are talking about two different things. The answer over there does not answer this question.

I just realized you closed it yourself. May I ask why you were convinced to close?

I solved it with the answer I linked. The cookie was not saved because I was putting the 'include' in the wrong request. It must be in the request receiving the cookie not in the requests using it

No that doesn’t do anything because you are dealing with the same origin; "localhost". If you close the browser the cookies will all still be lost.

Deletion on close is a separate problem (downstream). Different ports are different origins (even if both on localhost) and include solves it.

Has this been solved? "If I receive a cookie I should be able to see it in the ChromeDevTools under cookies I suppose, so this seems a different problem".

Yes, by using 'include' in the login request now the cookie is visible under cookies

The cookies that you sent to the browser has neither Max-Age nor Expires attribute. Such cookies are called session cookies because they live only for the lifetime of the particular browser session. Once you close that session (close the tab or the browser), they will be lost.
If you want them to live past the particular session, you should set either a Max-Age or Expires attribute. Max-Age is preferable according to the current web standards (not for the scope of this answer). If you set both Max-Age and Expires, Max-Age takes precedence.

I cannot see the cookie under application (devTools) even before closing of reloading the window though

Check Session Storage.
